# JQuery form gets submitted even validation is returning false

Tags: jquery, validation

My below mentioned code still submits form on special character in name field. Validation works but If I submit repeatedly it breaks and submits the form with special chars in name.

What could be the reason for this?

```
$("#fee").submit(function(){
   trimmedValue = $.trim($("#name").val());
   $("#name").val(trimmedValue);
   typevalue = $("input:radio[@name='type']:radio:checked").val();
   if(typevalue=="FLAT" && !isFloat($("#amount").val())) {
   alert("Amount should be number with proper decimal formatting");
   $("#amount").val("0.0");
    return false;
}
var noSpecialChars = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g;
if (noSpecialChars.test($("#name").val())) {
    alert("Please enter valid fee Name. Do not enter special characters"  );
    return false;
}

if(typevalue=="PERCENTAGE" && !isFloat($("#percentage").val())) {
   alert("percentage should be number with proper decimal formatting");
   $("#percentage").val("0.0");
    return false;
}
if(typevalue=="FLAT" && $("#amount").val()=="0.0") {
    return confirm("Do you really want the amount to be 0.0 ?");
}
if(typevalue=="PERCENTAGE" && $("#percentage").val()=="0.0") {
    return confirm("Do you really want the percentage to be 0.0 ?");
}
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In which browser(s) can you reproduce this?

I did it on Firefox 3.5.2, but couldn't reproduce it on IE 6.0. After exploring some more, I noticed that in this line ...

```
if (noSpecialChars.test($("#name").val())) {
```

... the call to .test() was returning `true`, then `false`, in an alternating pattern (in Firefox only) suggesting some problem with the `RegExp`. So I tried replacing the implicit creation of the RegExp like this:

```
    //var noSpecialChars = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g;        
    var noSpecialChars = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
```

And that fixed the problem for me.

Comment: thanks this fixed the issue. Would like to know how to debug in this scenarios.

Comment: No problem - in this case I debugged it in a pretty low-tech fashion, by adding a textarea element to the page and writing the result of noSpecialChars.test($("#name").val()) to that textarea. I also used Firebug a bit to discount some early hypotheses.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the interpreter is never reaching `return false;` on pressing repeatedly and is instead submitting the form to the `href` specified for the form.

If you have an `href` in your form tag, try removing it and inserting the property just before return is called.

Comment: I dont have href attribute for form. I have added action as well as method attribute.